# tools for checking hard disk failure

Tags: linux

Fedora 13

I am just wondering if there are any tools for checking the life of the hard disk. I had my hard disk for 4 years. And now I think it is having some problems.

Is there any tools I can use to check the condition of the hard disk?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`smartctl`](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/man/smartctl.8.html)

Comment: Yes, I have checked. smart-notifier

Answer (score 3):

Check your hard disk's manufacturer website. (Will be good if you mention your HDD brand on the question). For example, if it's *Seagate* I recommend you download [SeaTools](http://www.seagate.com/support/seatools/).