# Live tools for hard disk check, repair and reformat

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, repair, livecd, check-disk

In the old days, I had a floppy with CHCKDSK and other tools for checking hard disk failures, repairing them and, if necessary, reformating them. I recently tried to reinstall XP on an old computer, but got errors related to the hard disk. The XP installation CD can't handle it, so I need something more powerful.

Anybody can advise on a set of live tools on a bootable CD-ROM for advanced disk management (checking, repairing, reformating in NTFS, partitioning,...) Especially the NTFS is bugging me.

I've checked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/195953/tools-for-checking-hard-disk-failure), but the answer isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimate Boot CD can be gotten here: http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html
does what you want and WAY more

Comment: thx a lot, exactly what I looked for.